# Serial Port WriteLine sometimes fails

Tags: c#, serial-port

I wrote a simple program which send an AT command over serial port.
I followed the instruction 
[MSDN EXAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx)

Serial Port (38400,N,8,1)

```
serialPort1.PortName = "COM" + "5";// textBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            if (!(serialPort1.IsOpen))
                serialPort1.Open();


            // if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 || listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                serialPort1.WriteLine("atrst");
            // else
            //     serialPort1.WriteLine("araprst");

            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

When I use the WriteLine command sometimes the AT command is not send to the port. 
Any idea why?, 
Is there a way to know the WriteLine(String) fail?

Comment: What is your code though? How big is the command, what is your baud rate.

Comment: Did you try handling the [ErrorReceived event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived.aspx)?

Comment: Is this your actual code? you don't seem to be setting anything up or even initialising the SerialPort.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few causes for what you have described, and that MSDN article has some... interesting... code. From your code snippet I can see that you arn't properly setting up the serial port, so i'll post a working example, with the settings you have given, and hope that it helps.

```
serialPort = new SerialPort(
                "COM5",      // port name
                38400,       // baud rate
                Parity.None, // parity
                8,           // bits
                StopBits.One // stop bits
            );

serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

serialPort.Open();
serialPort.Write("atrst");
serialPort.Close();
```

This is a very bare-bones approach and does not include error handling, but it will work for a serial device with the settings you have given. Unless the Handshaking is wrong, which given the high baud rate, is quite possible and something you should look into.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply; the problem is not with setting up the serial port.
All the configuration of the port was done in the properties windows.
I also tried your code but the problem remain the same, sometimes the packet is not transmitted to the serial port

Comment: Do you have the correct handshaking? Are you sure the packet isn't transmitted, maybe the device just isn't expecting data at that time and drops it. To test you should use a mix of http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/ and `putty` to see if the stream is actually sending the data.